# Python: Fastest way to write large integer to file

Tags: python, string, file-io, integer, output

I want to write a really large integer from Python to a textfile, about 10 to 1000 Megabyte.

The following options have the same speed, unfortunately both are really slow:

```
import time
import pickle

num = 17**(10**7)

t1=time.time()
pickle.dump( num , open( "save2.p", "wb" ) )
t2=time.time()
print(str(t2-t1))

t3=time.time()
file = open("testfile2.txt","w") 
file.write(str(num))
file.close()
t4=time.time()
print(str(t4-t3))
```

(of course, the value of `num` is just a placeholder for another big integer)

**My questions:**

1. Is there a faster way to write a human-readable file with the decimal digits?
2. If not, how can I write it faster without human-readability?

Who can help?

Comment: Does this need to be human-readable?

Comment: Yes, human-readable please :)

Comment: I have to ask, *why* does it have to be human readable? Are you actually going to inspect those digits? The conversion to `str`, i.e. a human-readable string, is what's taking so long. If you used a raw binary representation it would be much faster.

Comment: unless you can pickle it, you're kind of stuck with str(int) and if that's too slow, it's because it actually takes time to write a gigabyte.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid binary numbers and to calculate in base 10 from the beginning? If yes, we could avoid the conversion...

Comment: You have a lot of questions. Which one are we answering? Just how to write a specific format? Sounds like a job for the modulo operator (or just division).

Comment: What do you mean? `int` objects are fundamentally represented as binary numbers, arbitrary sized in python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random

f=open("filename.txt","w")
char=""
ints=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
for i in range(10**10): #Ten to the power of ten
  char+=random.choice(ints)
if char.startswith("0"):
  char=char[1:]
f.write(char)
f.close()
```

If you want to read the integer, you write this:

```
myInt=int(open("filename.txt","r").read())
```

Hope this helps!